# How do I setup a cron job to run every 3 hours from afternoon to midnight?

Tags: cron, aws-lambda

I need to create a cron job that run every 3 hours from 12 pm to 12am so it would run at 12pm 3pm 6pm 9pm and 12 am.
I have a cron script running on AWS Lambda and they have 6 fields for the cron time.
I think it was to be something along the lines of:

```
0 */3 * * * *
```

but I know this is wrong, can't figure it out. 
How can I do this?

I've tried

```
0 0,12,15,18,21  * * *
```

but I get this error: http://screencast.com/t/7tH2wnseyc

> There was an error creating the event source mapping: Parameter ScheduleExpression is not valid.

Comment: The cron syntax is valid. The question is how you specify it through the GUI tool you're using. Your screenshot shows an (i) icon next to the "Schedule" field; presumably clicking it will show you some kind of information.

Comment: From the online text Lambda appears to want a year so add an extra "*" at the end.  I edited my answer below to include the with and without the expected year.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron  you can use commas create a list for a given field so something like should work

```
0 0,12,15,18,21  * * *
```

This will run at 12, 3, 6, 9, and midnight at the top of the hour.   If the Cron format wants a year then add another *

```
0 0,12,15,18,21  * * * *
```

Comment: Is there a diff way I can do this? I keep getting an error http://screencast.com/t/7tH2wnseyc

Comment: try adding another '*'  I looked up lambda and it is looking for a "year" as the last *.  Not all Cron Formats want the year.   I edited the answer above to include if the cron wants year

Answer (score 7):

AWS Cloudwatch Events currently requires a question mark in either the day-of-week or day-of-month slot. Here is the cron expression I used to do accomplish the task:

```
0 12,15,18,21,0 * * ? *
```

In Cloudwatch Events, you can now tell if you're on the right track because it displays trigger dates below your expression

[image: cron expression]

Answer (score 3):

Based on http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-scheduled-events.html

```
cron(0 0/3 * * * *)
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following

```
0 0,12,15,18,21 * * * /path/command
```

where the cron runs at 00:00, 12:00, 15:00, 18:00, 21:00 each day.